# Role of normality of the Klein group in solving a quartic using Lagrange resolvents

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, normal-subgroups, quartics

There are several ways how a useful resolvent for solving a quartic equation can be defined, e.g. (the roots are `a, b, c, d`)

1. `(a + b)(c + d)`
2. `ab + cd`
3. Let `X = a + bi - c - di`, then we take `X * complex_conjugate(X)`

All these expressions have an orbit of size 3 under S4 and actually the same orbit under the Klein group V4. Since V4 is the normal subgroup that "saves" the solvability of A4 (therefore S4), I wonder whether there's an explanation for the role its normality plays in existence of the resolvents given above.